# Remove null values [JOLT]

Tags: json, null, jolt

How to remove null values using JOLT?

```json
[
  {
    "age_restrictions": "0+",
    "autobidding_mode": "second_price",
    "banner_uniq_shows_limit": null,
    "budget_limit": 100,
    "budget_limit_day": null,
    "conversion_funnel_id": null,
    "date_end": "2024-02-29",
    "date_start": "2024-01-11",
    "documents": [],
    "dooh_settings": null,
    "enable_clickid": true,
    "enable_offline_goals": false,
    "enable_utm": false,
    "event_limit": null,
    "from_export_vkcom": false,
    "interactions": [],
    "interface_read_only": false,
    "language": "ru",
    "marketplace_app_client_id": null,
    "max_price": "0.00",
    "mixing": "recommended",
    "name": "Rec_site_video_test",
    "objective": "branding_universal_banner",
    "package_id": 3509,
    "panel_id": null,
    "price": "70.00",
    "read_only": false,
    "social": false,
    "uniq_shows_limit": 5,
    "uniq_shows_period": "month",
    "utm": null
  }
]
```

I know about function `=recursivelySquashNulls` and it works okay. But what if I need to remove null values only for specific fields? I need to remove NULLs for (sometimes these fields are not null, so I need to be careful): `panel_id,marketplace_app_client_id,dooh_settings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following transformation in order to remove those attributes if they have null values

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "panel_id|marketplace_app_client_id|dooh_settings": {
          "": { "*": "" },
          "*": { "@1": "&2" } // non-nulls from the determined set
        },
        "*": "&" // other elements
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work. Now I've `ToBeDeleted` instead of `null` for these fields, but they are not removed.

Comment: Thanks! But now another problem: all NULL fields removed(

Comment: @takotsubo I've just fixed the issues, take care.